# How to use one to one/zero mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have two tables: Person And Vehicle

Person record can exist independently , that means, a person may or may not associated with a vehicle. But the Vehicle record can not exist without person.
In the nutshell,

Vehicle table has Person_Id has foreign key, where Person_Id is the primary key of the person table.

Now to define this relationship in hibernate I have used one to one mapping as follows:

```
public class Person

{

    private int person_id;

    @OnetoOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Vehicle vehicle;
}

public class Vehicle {

    private int vehicle_id;

    @OnetoOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

}
```

Now, when I try to save the Person who has Vehicle, the person objects gets saved successfully. I just use `session.save(person)` and both the objects gets saved successfully.
   On the other hand, if I try to save a Person, who does not have a Vehicle , i.e, the vechile object is null for that Person object. Then an exception is thrown i.e

> ConstraintVoilationException cannot insert null into the
>   Vehicle.Person_Id column.

Please help me to understand, how can I save a person object when my vehicle object is null.

This seems to be a 1 to 1/0  mappping.

Comment: Do you have NOT NULL constraint in Person_id Column?

Comment: Yes, the database tables were created through sql scripts and not via hibernate. and there is not null constraint on person_id column.

Comment: It is not possible to insert null in NOT NULL columns you have to remove that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If your database schema is generated from annotations, please use a **optional** parameter in you OneToOne mapping in Person.

If your databse is created by hand, allow null on database side.

From: [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#optional())

Comment: The JavaDoc states: `Whether the association is optional. If set to false then a non-null relationship must always exist.` and then states: `Default: true`. So if they haven't defined it, surely nulls would be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this annotation in vehicle class person attribute

```
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Comment: I used this, but still it is throwing the same exception